# Transform a boost::array into NumericVector in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, boost, rcpp

In my C++ script (run in R using Rcpp), I defined :

```
typedef boost::array< double ,3 > state_type;
```

Now, I want to create a function to transform a state_type variable to a Rcpp::NumericVector variable, and another function that do the inverse. How can do that?
I need to do that in order to use R function into C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
Rcpp::NumericVector boost_array_to_nvec(state_type const& s) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector nvec(s.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        nvec[i] = s[i];
    }
    return nvec;
}
state_type nvec_to_boost_array(Rcpp::NumericVector const& nvec) {
    state_type s;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        s[i] = nvec[i];
    }
    return s;
}
...
state_type s {0,0,0};
Rcpp::NumericVector nvec = boost_array_to_nvec(s);
s = nvec_to_boost_array(nvec);
```

If you have to do this a lot of times. This might not be the most efficient way of doing the transformation. But now you have to look that nvec is already allocated to the correct size.

```
void boost_array_to_nvec(state_type const& s, Rcpp::NumericVector& nvec) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        nvec[i] = s[i];
    }
}
void nvec_to_boost_array (Rcpp::NumericVector const& nvec, state_type& s) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        s[i] = nvec[i];
    }
}
...
state_type s {0,0,0};
Rcpp::NumericVector nv(3);
boost_array_to_nvec(s, nv);
nvec_to_boost_array(nv, s);
```

Comment: I use the boost library to solve ode, and it requires to have boost::array variables.

Comment: Did my solution from yesterday work for you for finding the boost headers?

Comment: No, it didn't work, so I used Dirk's solution, but thanks anyway.

Comment: It would also have worked with the Makevars.win file. The difference is that BH just puts them at a predefined R place and you have no control over which boost version is installed. But that's beside the point. The above should work for this problem.

Comment: @KavehVahedipour  You may not know what the [BH](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=BH) package does -- portable access to a subset of Boost that will work on any R platform _without the linker, path and makefile headaches_.  Similarly here, as Ralf said, there are better (close) approaches outlines at the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org). Take a look, you may like what you find.

Comment: I did understand. The part of boost that covers odeint.h does not require linking. I agree with you, when we get to boost parts that do require linking.

Comment: @AnthonyHauser did my answer above week? I'm doing this from a phone and cannot compile anything :).

Comment: @Kaveh, it seems to work. I tried to do the other way round, i.e. transform a vector to boost::array, but it doesn't work. I actually don't know how to initialize a boost::array variable.

Comment: If it does, I'd appreciate if you'd accept the solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have *seamless* integration you will have to extend `Rcpp::as<T>(obj)` and `Rcpp::wrap(obj)`. How to do this is covered in the vignette [Extending Rcpp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf). However, there is also an [excellent entry in the Rcpp gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-templated-wrap-and-as-for-seamingless-interfaces/) that already covers a very similar case: Converting to and from  `boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double>`.

If you are content with only using `state_type` and not the general template, then you can use something like this:

```
#include <RcppCommon.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <boost/array.hpp>
typedef boost::array< double ,3 > state_type;

namespace Rcpp {
// non-intrusive extension via template specialisation
template <> state_type as(SEXP s);
// non-intrusive extension via template specialisation
template <> SEXP wrap(const state_type &s);
}

#include <Rcpp.h>

// define template specialisations for as and wrap
namespace Rcpp {
template <> state_type as(SEXP stsexp) {
  Rcpp::NumericVector st(stsexp);
  state_type result;
  if (st.size() != result.size()) Rcpp::stop("Incompatible length!");
  std::copy(st.begin(), st.end(), result.begin());
  return result;
}

template <> SEXP wrap(const state_type &st) {
  Rcpp::NumericVector result(st.size());
  std::copy(st.begin(), st.end(), result.begin());
  return Rcpp::wrap(result);
}
}

// make use of the new possibilities
// [[Rcpp::export]]
state_type alterStateType(state_type &st) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < st.size(); ++i) {
    st[i] = i * st[i];
  }
  return st;
}

/*** R
alterStateType(1:3)
*/
```